# Generics and ArgumentCaptor in Mockito

Tags: java, generics, mockito

In Mockito's verify I want to capture an argument of type `Consumer<String>`. How should I write the line to avoid type erasure?

I'm reached this point and it doesn't compile:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Consumer<String>> captor = ArgumentCaptor.<Consumer<String>, Consumer<String>>forClass(Consumer<String>.class);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation of `ArgumentCaptor`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) although this class is generic, it doesn't perform any validation:

> This utility class **don't do any type checks**, the generic signatures are only there to avoid casting in your code.

Hence, if you make use of row types it wouldn't be less type-safe, but there's a drawback - the compiler will issue a warning.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArgumentCaptor<Consumer<String>> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Consumer.class);
```

There's a cleaner option which also mentioned in the documentation linked above, namely to declare the captor as a field and annotate it with [`@Captor`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.9/org/mockito/Captor.html).

```
@Captor
ArgumentCaptor<Consumer<String>> captor;
```

Comment: I really like the @Captor annotation